# Sum outliers together in Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

If I have data that looks like this

```
1, 500
2, 200
3, 100
4, 1
10, 1
50, 1
100, 1
```

Then in a column chart the `100, 1` row will make the graph very long. Is there a way to tell Google to smartly sum outliers such that the graph would contain `10+, 3`?

I can manually do it, but then it's misleading and looks like there are 3 entries for the value 10. Ideally the graph should display

```
1, 500
2, 200
3, 100
4, 1
10+, 3
```

where the right side of the x axis has some way to indicate that there aren't 3 items with value 10 but rather 3 items of value 10 or higher.

Comment: there are no _standard_ options available for this, but not sure i follow what the end result should be, if you could clarify, i'm sure i could help...